# Shiny progressBar and actual computation time

Tags: progress-bar, shiny

I am new to Shiny. I noticed that although the progress bar is very useful feature to provide feedback to the user, however it appears that one has to pre-determine the computation time to properly display the progress bar. The computation time for computation is variable in my script depending on the size of data fed.

Do I understand correctly that progressbar does not necessarily reflect the progress of the actual calculations if so, Is there a way to connect the progress bar to actual computation time?

Comment: this http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html should help!

Comment: This is only possible if you can insert `updateProgress` into the middle of your computation code.